# Bootstrap radio buttons does change when selected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button

I used this Bootstrap 3 code to change radios into buttons:

```html
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="sim_type" value="option 1" checked>Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="sim_type" value="option 2">Option 2
    </label>
</div>
```

It works well in the jsfiddle but in my website the color of buttons are not changed when clicked. It always is like this:

[image]

But the submitted value is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code to add .active class manually:

```
// Change the color of selected radio button
$('label.btn').click(function() {
     $(this).parent('.btn-group').children('label.btn').addClass('active');
     $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

**UPDATE:**
This code is not needed. You just need to add class 'active' to one of labels initially.
This code works well without any js:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="sim_type" value="option 1" checked>Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="sim_type" value="option 2">Option 2
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: but how can radios be turned into button you are changing the architecture.